# Cron expression of every 3 minutes between specific time

Tags: cron, scheduler, cron-task, nodejs-server, node-schedule

Here is the scenario:-
I want to run a specific function in my NodeJs application and for that i am using NodeScheduler

I know i can use this expression

> */3 8-15 * * *

for every 3 minutes between 8 AM to 3 PM but i want to run it between 8:30 AM to 3:15 PM but Cron expression for this which i made is certainly wrong

> 30-15/3 8-15 * * *

does anyone know what can be correct cron expression for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

The normal `cron` doesn't give you that level of expressiveness but there's nothing stopping you from putting further restrictions in the command portion of the entry:

```
*/3 8-15 * * * [[ 1$(date +\%H\%M) -ge 10830 ]] && [[ 1$(date +\%H\%M) -le 11515 ]] && payload
```

This will actually run the `cron` job itself every three minutes between 8am and 4pm, but the payload (your script that does the actual work) will only be called if the current time is between 8:30am and 3:15pm.

The placing of `1` in front of the time is simply a trick to avoid issues treating numbers starting with zero as octal.

---

In fact, I have a script `withinTime.sh` that proves useful for this sort of thing:

```
usage() {
    [[ -n "$1" ]] && echo "$1"
    echo "Usage: withinTime <hhmmStart> <hhmmEnd>"
}

validTime() {
    [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]{4}$ ]] || return 1  # Ensure 0000-9999.
    [[ $1 -le 2359 ]] || return 1         # Ensure 0000-2359.
    return 0
}

# Parameter checking.

[[ $# -ne 2 ]] && { usage "ERROR: Not enough parameters"; exit 1; }
validTime "$1" || { usage "ERROR: invalid hhmmStart '$1'"; exit 1; }
validTime "$2" || { usage "ERROR: invalid hhmmEnd '$2'"; exit 1; }

now="1$(date +%H%M)"
[[ ${now} -lt 1${1} ]] && exit 1  # If before start.
[[ ${now} -gt 1${2} ]] && exit 1  # If after end.

# Within range, flag okay.
exit 0
```

With this script in your path, you can simplify the `cron` command a little:

```
*/3 8-15 * * * /home/pax/bin/withinTime.sh 0830 1515 && payload
```